# SQLAlchemy: Select count of related many-to-many elements

Tags: python, sql, many-to-many, sqlalchemy

I have a many to many relationship between two tables/objects: Tag and Content. `Tag.content` is the relationship from a tag to all content which has this tag.

Now I'd like to find out the number of content objects assigned to a tag (for all tags, otherwise I'd simply use `len()`). The following code almost works:

```
cnt = db.func.count()
q = db.session.query(Tag, cnt) \
    .outerjoin(Tag.content) \
    .group_by(Tag) \
    .order_by(cnt.desc())
```

However, it will never return a zero count for obvious reasons - there is at least one row per tag after all due to the `LEFT JOIN` used. This is a problem though since I'd like to get the correct count for all tags - i.e. `0` if a tag is orphaned.

So I wonder if there's a way to achieve this - obviously without sending *n+1* queries to the database. A pure-SQL solution might be ok too, usually it's not too hard to map such a solution to SA somehow.

`.filter(Tag.content.any())` removes the results with the incorrect count, but it will do so by removing the rows from the resultset altogether which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I needed to use DISTINCT in the COUNTs:

```
cnt = db.func.count(db.distinct(Content.id))
```

Comment: Doesn't GROUP BY also translate to distinct?